# Select body + media_url on each iteration Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a functionality to send three MMS (via Twilio) to the phone number entered by the user in a form.

I followed this tutorial from Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/sending-via-rest

The `:from` and `:to` are working no problem and I am able to send the MMS without any problems when the `:body` and `:media_url` are hardcoded like in the example.

I have all my pictures and corresponding texts into a table named Messages and I am able to randomly select two of them by using `Message.order("RANDOM()").limit(2)`, which gives me an array similar to this:

```
    {
    :id         => 24,
    :body       => "BODY #1",
    :media_url  => "MEDIA_URL #1",
    :created_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:21:39 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:21:39 UTC +00:00
    },
    {
    :id         => 21,
    :body       => "BODY #2",
    :media_url  => "MEDIA_URL #2",
    :created_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:21:39 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:21:39 UTC +00:00
    }
    {
    :id         => 25,
    :body       => "BODY #3",
    :media_url  => "MEDIA_URL #3",
    :created_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:41:39 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Fri, 24 Jun 2016 15:41:39 UTC +00:00
    }
```

Here's my method to send MMS:

```
def send_text_message
    twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]
    sender_number = twilio_phone_number.sample

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

    3.times {
    @twilio_client.account.messages.create(
      :from => sender_number,
      :to => self.phone,
      :body => "I want the corresponding body here",
      :media_url => "I want the corresponding media_url here"
    )
  }
```

As I said, I have my array of three randomly selected messages from the table and now I need to iterate over this array in order to include them one by one, without creating duplicate as well.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Controller:

```
def create
    @home = Home.new(home_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @home.save
        @home.send_text_message
        format.html { redirect_to @home, notice: 'MMS Sent' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @home }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @home.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something but what problem is? You said that you have array of three randomly selected messages. So what is the problem?

Comment: I can't get the body and media_url of each objects in my array to populate my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this, can't you?

```
random_messages.each do |message|
  @twilio_client.account.messages.create(
    from:      sender_number,
    to:        self.phone,
    body:      message[:body],
    media_url: message[:media_url]
  ) 
end
```

Here I suggest that `random_messages` is the method that returns your random messages array.